# Move dates from week to week in moment js

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I'm building an schedule online that allows users to move a moment from a specific time of the week to another week. Using MomentJS, I would like to know if there is a ready made solution or else, figure a way to achieve this.

Here is a use case for example:

1. A user has an appointment for the Friday 28 of December 2018
2. The user want's to move it 2 weeks later
3. The expected result would be Friday 11 of January 2019

If it helps, here is a base code for the situation (in TypeScript):

```
let firstAppointment = moment("2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z");
let amountOfWeek:number = 2;
//do the operation...
```

**EDIT 1**
I've ran some tests, here is the result. It seems that the result date is off by a few hours

```js
let firstAppointment = moment("2018-12-28T00:03:00.000Z");
firstAppointment.add(2,"weeks");
console.log(firstAppointment.toISOString(false));
//result: 2019-01-10T19:03:00.000Z
```

Could this be related to the time zone?

Comment: Sadly time zones can always be a bit tricky. Try using [`UTC`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) for all your dates.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alex Kucksdorf, here is the solution. In order to compute the right time, we need to go into UTC mode, provided by MomentJS 
[Moment.js UTC documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

```
let firstAppointment = moment.utc("2018-12-28T00:03:00.000Z");
firstAppointment.add(2,"weeks");
console.log(firstAppointment.toISOString());
```